# my_contract,estimateGas() crashes and "eth_estimateGas" returns incorrect value

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, gas, gas-limit, gas-estimate

I'm trying to estimate Gas for a contract method (both using `parity` and `geth` - tried `web3py` and `web3js`). Contract is deployed and proven to be working.

When I use:

- `estimateGas` and `geth` (providing: `to, from, data` I get `gas > 6 700 000`, which seems to be an error as it's the whole available gas for the current block
- `estimateGas` and `parity` (providing: `to, from, data` I get the following error: `Internal("Requires higher than upper limit of 1000000000000")`
- `JSONRPC` and `trace_call`returns around `49000` (`parity`)
- `JSONRPC` and method `eth_estimateGas` returns `77858` (both for `parity` and `geth`)
- however when I actually create a transaction it consumes much more `Gas Used By Txn: 108140` - which doesn't match the number returned by `eth_estimateGas` - if I click `trace` on Etherscan (`parity/geth`) - gas from the traces matches `77858`, however `108140` is used to process the transaction.

Am I missing something here? How can I calculate the gas properly? There is nothing unusual in the contract - constant number of steps. I believe that I should be able to even calculate this manually with a pen and paper.

I've tried a few transactions and gas used by txn is always higher from `30000` to `32000` units than estimated gas.

Comment: Are you putting in the data parameter?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above I provide `to`, `from` and `data`. Have you came across similar issues?

Comment: This seems quite weird. How are you calculating the data parameter?

Comment: I wrote a function to calculate `data` parameter. In order to validate my function, I've created 5 real transactions and obtained `data` by `web3.eth.getTransaction()` and it was matching `data` generated by my function. 
I've tried even creating a transaction, getting data by web3.eth.getTransaction() and estimating gas in the same second, but returned value was different than the one on etherscan.